# How to recognize an OTG USB port on an embedded device?

Tags: usb, embedded

Sorry for the noob question, I'm trying to flash a new firmware on a tv box with rk3066. The [datasheet](http://rockchip.fr/RK3066%20datasheet%20V1.0.pdf) says that the chip has OTG capability but there are 3 usb ports on the board and I can't tell which one it is:

[image]

How can I tell which port supports OTG? Also would it be safe to try connecting each port to my pc to test which port gets recognized or would the VCC voltage from the board damage my PC?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I thought USB OTG was always over micro-USB or USB-C connectors, not type-A connectors.

Comment: None of those 3 USB-A ports is an OTG port. An OTG connector would be either 'mini' or 'micro' with 5 pins, or a type-C, and it looks me me as though all 3 of those ports are likely connected to U7 - probably a USB hub.

Comment: There are type A OTG ports, for example here http://ugoos.net/blog/rockchip-firmware-reflashing-guide. When I connect the USB stick to the first usb port on the left it doesn't work but it works on the other two for some reason.

Comment: Does your Cruzer drive work in all 3 ports?

Comment: @Ale..chenski No it works on the second and the third ports but not on the first one near the HDMI port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no OTG Type-A ports, simply because the 4-pin Type-A connector is lacking the extra ID pin that is necessary to switch port roles from "device" to "host" or vice versa. If some goofy product has a Type-A port that is used to re-flash firmware, this is just a wrong use of "OTG" terminology and misuse of USB specifications. Most likely this port is pre-configured as "device", and it shouldn't be using the receptacle of Type-A.

If my guess about the Rockchip-based devices is correct, their "OTG port" would be the one that doesn't have VBUS source. Therefore USB flash drives won't work in that port.  You can either try to measure VBUS voltage on empty receptacles, or just try your USB flash. The port that doesn't have VBUS or flash fails is your "OTG" port. You will need a Type-A <-> Type-A cable (again, illegal from USB standpoint) to reprogram your device. Keep in mind that A-A cables might have D+/D- swapped, so don't be surprised if some (illegal) cables won't work for you.